# Specify content of a submap based on a field

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Maybe my question has already been answered but I am stuck with a submap specification.

Imagine I have two possibilities like that

```
{:type :a
 :spec {:name "a"}}

{:type :b
 :spec {:id "b"}}
```

In short: the `:spec` keys depends on the type. For the type `:a`, the `:spec` must contain the field `:name` and for type `:b` the spec must contain the field `:id`.

I tried this:

```
(s/def ::type keyword?)

(defmulti input-type ::type)
(defmethod input-type :a
  [_]
  (s/keys :req-un [::name]))
(defmethod input-type :b
  [_]
  (s/keys :req-un [::id]))
(s/def ::spec (s/multi input-type ::type))

(s/def ::input (s/keys :req-un [::type ::spec]))
```

This tells me: no method ([:spec nil]).
I think I see why: maybe type is not acccessible.
So I thought to make a multi-spec of a higher level (based on the whole map).

Problem: I do not know how to define `:spec` based on `:type` because they have the same name. Do you know how to perform this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
(s/def ::type keyword?)
(s/def ::id string?)
(s/def ::name string?)
(s/def :id/spec (s/keys :req-un [::id]))
(s/def :name/spec (s/keys :req-un [::name]))
```

To accommodate the two different *meanings* for your `:spec` map, we can define those in different namespaces: `:id/spec` and `:name/spec`. Note that the non-namespace suffix of these keywords are both `spec` and our `keys` specs are using un-namespaced keywords. These are "fake" namespaces here, but you could also define these in other, "real" namespaces in your project.

```
(defmulti input-type :type)
(defmethod input-type :a [_]
  (s/keys :req-un [::type :name/spec]))
(defmethod input-type :b [_]
  (s/keys :req-un [::type :id/spec]))

(s/def ::input (s/multi-spec input-type :type))

(s/valid? ::input {:type :a, :spec {:name "a"}})
=> true
```

You can also get samples of this spec:

```
(gen/sample (s/gen ::input))
=>
({:type :a, :spec {:name ""}}
 {:type :b, :spec {:id "aI"}} ...
```